# Is it possible to validate user in backend without user providing credientals?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I need to make a page with a button that fills certain text area with data from database. However I need it to also require administrator privileges.

Is it possible to have an API method that doesn't require credientals, but an Identity session instead? Ideally something that gets a `HttpContext.User`?

I don't know anything about JavaScript, I managed to put together this thing:

```
const url = '/api/clients/';

function getItems() { 
    fetch(url + document.getElementById('input').value)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => _displayItems(data));
}

function _displayItems(arrayOfResults) {
    const textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

    textbox.value = "";

    arrayOfResults.forEach(json => {
        textbox.value += json.deviceIdentifier + "\n";
    });
}
```

I have an API endpoint at `http://localhost/api/clients/{string}` that does a database query and it works as expected. But I can not allow just about anybody to access that data and I have trouble figuring out how to make user:

- not provide his credentials
- be able to use it with minimal effort (ie. just click the button and get results)
- be unable to use this endpoint while not currently logged in on the website

Normally I just use this line to get the user that tries to access the controller:

`var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User));`

and go from there. But when my JS script is accessing the API it doesn't provide a way to validate using `HttpContext`, from what I'm seeing.

Comment: For a webserver to know who you are, it needs something to identify you. This is usually done by passing in credentials that return an access token that can be used for every subsequent request in the HTTP headers.

Comment: If the page is hosted on the same website where the user logged in, the API should be getting the same cookie used for all other requests.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond yesterday. Yes, the script is run from the same website the API is on. Strangely I made an authorization mechanism that worked on localhost, but doesn't work on production server at all. I use a load balancer that puts my website in it's own directory, could that be the cause? I had related problems with logging out previously.